# Can someone help me like how can I delete a character in a certain position (row, column) in emu 8086 assembly?

Tags: assembly, emu8086

How can I delete a character in a certain position (row, column) in emu 8086 assembly? Can someone explain me properly ?

Comment: Overwrite it at this position with space character (0x20).

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.